# Do xhtml or xml allow comments to be started by user defined tags?

Tags: xml, tags, xhtml, comments, user-defined

Reusing old php-code and html-files I wanted to comment out large sections, but that's not too easily achievable, because those sections contain comments themselves already.

Looking at the helpfile for php and the 5.3 html syntax at w3 I found out, that comments have a very limited amount of tags one could use.

As I remember I have read years ago about some coding language which allows userdefined comment-tags, albeit they had to follow some rules.

Especially I wonder
- if userdefined comment-tags are possible in xhtml?
- if userdefined comment-tags are possible in xml?
- if it's possible in xhtml or xml, shouldn't it be possible in html, too, to define new comment-tags?

Comment: There once was a proprietary element <comment> in IE (which apparently survived until IE8), but it was never supported by other browsers. Anyway, what does "comments have a very limited amount of tags one could use" mean?

Comment: Many editors like oXygen will auto strip the inside comments when you perform such an edit

Comment: @KevinBrown Yeah, I have to start to use a proper editor. I didn't want to change the environment, but denying the necessity to change doesn't yield anything. +1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**No.**

HTML comments (all versions, including [HTML4](https://www.w3.org/TR/1999/REC-html401-19991224/intro/sgmltut.html#h-3.2.4), [XHTML](https://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/), and [HTML5](https://www.w3.org/TR/html52/syntax.html#comments)) and [XML comments](https://www.w3.org/TR/xml/#sec-comments) have always had the following form:

```
<!-- This is a comment -->
```

There are no "user-defined comment-tags" in HTML or XML.